# Why is MongoDB oplog size different between servers

Tags: mongodb

I have a ReplicaSet running fine once I ran `rs.stepDown()` and looking for `rs.status()` I get fine logs.

Here is one as evidence:

```
rsdev:SECONDARY> db.printSlaveReplicationInfo()
source: lab:27017
    syncedTo: Mon Jul 17 2017 09:20:52 GMT-0300 (BRT)
    0 secs (0 hrs) behind the primary
```

I got one problem with my application that if I change the primary to the server X which used to be the secondary than I just can't use its oplog as I was when using server Y as primary.

I know that when I have  a new member in the ReplicaSet it may will have the dataSet size smaller than its primary due to its age, delete, insert and so on.

But should its oplog size be different between them?

```
rsdev:PRIMARY> db.getReplicationInfo().usedMB
40543.1

rsdev:SECONDARY>  db.getReplicationInfo().usedMB
21734.5
```

This secondary server is the new one which I get into problem if become primary.

Both using wiredTiger storage.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't defined [in config](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/) (file or parameter; replication.oplogSizeMB) what size of opLog you wanted when node was initialized, it is [automatically set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/#oplog-size) base on free space on data disk. In wireTiger it's 5% of free disk space (990MB-50GB).

You can [change that oplog size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/change-oplog-size/) if you want, but after that you need to wait until it's full.

Answer (score 1):

As you said that you have done once `rs.stepDown` in replica set, As per `MongoDB BOL`   [rs.stepDown()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.stepDown/) is **New in version 3.0**. Before stepping down,  [rs.stepDown()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.stepDown/#rs.stepDown) will attempt to terminate long running user operations that would block the primary from stepping down, such as an index build, a write operation or a map-reduce job.

To avoid rollbacks, `rs.stepDown()`, by default, only steps down the primary if an electable secondary is completely caught up with the primary. The command will wait up to either 10 seconds or the `secondaryCatchUpPeriodSecs` for a secondary to catch up.

> **Note:** `rs.stepDown()` blocks all writes to the primary while it runs.

The [oplog](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-oplog) (operations log) is a special `capped collection` that keeps a rolling record of all operations that modify the data stored in your databases. MongoDB applies database operations on the primary and then records the operations on the primary’s oplog. The secondary members then copy and apply these operations in an asynchronous process. All replica set members contain a copy of the oplog, in the  [local.oplog.rs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/local-database/#local.oplog.rs) collection, which allows them to maintain the current state of the database.

When you start a replica set member for the first time, MongoDB creates an oplog of a default size For Unix and Windows systems for WiredTiger Storage Engine is

```
Default Oplog Size     Lower Bound  Upper Bound
5% of free disk space   990 MB       50 GB
```

For example, if an `oplog` is `5%` of free disk space and fills up in 24 hours of operations, then secondaries can stop copying entries from the oplog for up to 24 hours without becoming too stale to continue replicating. However, most replica sets have much lower operation volumes, and their `oplogs` can hold much higher numbers of operations.

As `rs.stepDown()` method here

```
rs.stepDown(stepDownSecs, secondaryCatchUpPeriodSecs)
```

Before making the `rs.stepDown` you have to make sure that The method only steps down the `primary` if an electable secondary is `up-to-date` with the `primary`, waiting up to `10 seconds`, by default, for a secondary to catch up.

> **Note** : `rs.stepDown()` provides a wrapper around the command
>   replSetStepDown.